# localstorage value reset after refreshing a window

Tags: javascript

I have a code below

```
var amount = document.getElementById('downloads-t76a');

var current = 3700;
document.getElementById("downloads-t76a").innerHTML = localStorage.userTotal;

function update()
{
amount.innerText = format(current);
}

setInterval(function(){
current += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
localStorage.setItem('userTotal', current);
update();
},2000);

function format(amount)
{
var d = Math.floor(amount).toString().split('');
var c = (Math.round((amount%1)*100)/100).toString().split('.')[1];
if(typeof c == 'undefined'){
    c = '00';
}else if(c.length == 1){
    c = c + '0';
}
var str = '';
for(i=d.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    str += d.splice(0,1);
    if(i%3 == 0 && i != 0) str += ',';
}
return str;
}
```

Basically after first time user goes to the site value starts at 3700, value is updated every 2 seconds. The problem is when I refresh the window value starts again at 3700, but I want it to be last updated value before user refreshed.

Comment: You can just get the value on page load via [localStorage.getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem). Then set it to 3700 if it doesn't exist. Be aware that localStorage always returns a string so you need to parse it into a number after doing `localStorage.getItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refresh your script starts new. So nothing from the previous code is accessible. Exactly the reason you are using localStorage.

```
var storageValue = localStorage.getItem('userTotal') ;
var current = storageValue === null ? 3700 : (+JSON.parse(storageValue));
```

Using the `+` operator as [getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) returns a DOMString. We need to convert it to a number.